# BigQuery Storage API Error: bqstorage_client

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am using BigQuery Storage API (beta) to load a large dataset in dataframe.

Here is my code:

```
 from google.cloud import bigquery
 from google.cloud import bigquery_storage_v1beta1

 bqclient = bigquery.Client(
  project='i-xxxx')
 bqstorageclient = bigquery_storage_v1beta1.BigQueryStorageClient()
 df= bqclient.query(query_string,job_config=query_config).result().to_dataframe(bqstorage_client=bqstorageclient)
```

But I got the below error:

```
 TypeError: to_dataframe() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bqstorage_client'
```

Any idea what is this error is about? is it a bug or I am missing sth here?

Updated:
pip freeze as requested:

```
google-api-core==1.8.0
google-api-python-client==1.7.7
google-auth==1.6.1
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.3
google-auth-oauthlib==0.2.0
google-cloud-bigquery==1.9.0
google-cloud-bigquery-storage==0.2.0
google-cloud-core==0.29.1
google-cloud-storage==1.13.2
google-resumable-media==0.3.1
googleapis-common-protos==1.5.5
```

Comment: Maybe you don't have the most recent version of the client library?

Comment: Could you add to the questions your `pip3 freeze` results regarding the BigQuery libraries?

Comment: @elliotte it seems the latest verion

Comment: @llompalles added google ones, SO doesnt allow to add all the list, do you want the version of any other lib?

Comment: restart the conda and it works now!

Comment: These lines of code worked for me: (1)query_jo = client.query(sql)  (2)df = query_job.to_arrow(bqstorage_client=bqstorageclient).to_pandas()